# Android Game and Server with notifications

Tags: android, notifications, server, google-play-games

Currently, I'm working on my new project - a (quite) simple game on Android allowing users to play with each other. One game is divided into few rounds, that users play separately. When one user has finished his round, application should send message to a server, which, in turn, should send notification to the other player with set of actions made by first player.

Beside that, players should be able to send invitations to the game to other players and server, for its own, should be able to send notifications, when, for example, user didn't make a move for a long time. (sort of reminders)

I'm wondering which technology/library/... I can use to make this work. I read a little bit about GCM, but I'm not sure it's good choice. I don't want my app to send some "pings" to server in every second/minute to check if it has something new happened. I want it to be as light and speed as possible.

Can you give me a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

@Tomek, 
First, probably you will will need to keep a persistent connection while the person is in the game to you server to have a minimal latency.

Second, you know java if you are writing on Android

Third, asynchronous event-driven server model might be a good choice.

I'd like to recommend you to take a look on netty
http://netty.io/

At the same time, Google has a multi-player API, but it is too vendor lock and the general idea behind is different
https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer